# Symfony 2 .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have a issue with the .htaccess, I have symfony 2 in a folder `mysite.com/service`

I execute the front controller with `mysite.com/service/web/app_dev.php/myruteapp`, works perfect, I put in the service folder a .htaccess with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

With this code I can execute the front controller from `mysite.com/service/app_dev.php/login` the problem it's I have a 404 with message

> No route found for "GET in"
>   404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
>   1 linked Exception:
>       ResourceNotFoundException »

The get URI send by Firefox it's `mysite.com/service/web/app_dev.php/_wdt/59e0f5`

How can execute correctly the front controller form service folder with out `web/app_dev.php`?

edit:

I fixed with a Alias in my apache rules

```
Alias /services /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/services/web

<Directory "/var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/services/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```